# Using sed, how do you print the first 'N' characters of a line?

Tags: shell, sed, grep

Using `sed` what is an one liner to print the first *n characters*?  I am doing the following:

```
grep -G 'defn -test.*' OctaneFullTest.clj  | sed ....
```

Answer (score 272, accepted):

Don't use `sed`, use `cut`:

```
grep .... | cut -c 1-N
```

If you MUST use `sed`:

```
grep ... | sed -e 's/^\(.\{12\}\).*/\1/'
```

Comment: Actually on a Cygwin system I'm working on now `cut` doesn't cut it while `sed` does.

Comment: Or even `sed -r 's/^(.{12}).*/\1/'`.

Comment: @fedorqui `-r` is apparently available on Linux, but not on Mac.

Comment: Exactly, it is not available on OSX.

Comment: FYI: 
`cut -c 1-N` (where N is a number) _does_ work on my Cygwin installation (cygwin v. 2.6, cut v. 8.25)
On OS X, use `sed -E` rather than `sed -r`, used elsewhere.

Comment: Note that `cut` [doesn't work with utf8 (yet)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163721).  `colrm` does (see manoflinux' answer below).

Comment: @PaulTomblin @fedorqui may be available in GNU-sed, `brew install gnu-sed`. then used `gsed` command.

Comment: @leetbacoon yes, there is always the gnu-X package to have the GNU-X package on OSX. It is good to remember!

Comment: Thank you for **also** providing the sed answer, because it isn't clear to me how to cut the length of only **one of several** match strings/groups with `cut`, so this answer is useful for people like me who already have a complex `sed` expression and don't know how to translate that to `cut`.

Answer (score 58):

```
colrm x
```

For example, if you need the first 100 characters:

```
cat file |colrm 101
```

It's been around for years and is in most linux's and bsd's (freebsd for sure), usually by default. I can't remember ever having to type `apt-get install colrm`.

Comment: This doesn't give the first 50n characters. It gives the n characters for every line of text

Comment: And `colrm` understands utf8.

Answer (score 11):

don't have to use grep either

an example:

```
sed -n '/searchwords/{s/^\(.\{12\}\).*/\1/g;p}' file
```

Answer (score 10):

How about **head** ?

```
echo alonglineoftext | head -c 9
```

Comment: I wonder how/if this works with non-ASCII/multi-byte characters

Comment: `head` will consider the whole stream as one single entry. If you pipe a text file into head, you won't get the first X chars of each line, but rather, the first X chars at all (ie. of the first line, period).

Answer (score 8):

To print the N first characters you can remove the N+1 characters up to the end of line:

```
$ sed 's/.//5g' <<< "defn-test"
defn
```

Answer (score 7):

Strictly with sed:

```
grep ... | sed -e 's/^\(.\{N\}\).*$/\1/'
```